# WIFI "C" terminal

Tags: thermostat, wifi

I recently purchased a WIFI thermostat that requires the use of the "C" terminal.  I do have an extra wire available to use on the C terminal that runs from the wall unit to the furnace. However, there is no terminal board/block at the furnace. The thermostat wires connect directly to the furnace wires and inside the unit, there is no terminal block.  This is an old GE unit and works fine. I just need to know where I can connect the "c" wire at the furnace.

Comment: Can you post photos of the furnace wiring and any wiring diagram you find? Also, what model is the furnace?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to add a pic

Comment: Upload the pictures to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link in the comments here, then we can edit them into your post for you

Comment: BTW, you don't need to make an account on imgur, just use the free no account upload button

Comment: if you have wire, you can add your own terminal anywhere along it. you don't even need a terminal, just a connection, twist-on nuts on a spliced wire for example...